# What is the trick to Scrape the NSE page?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I am trying to **scrape** this link `https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY`

This following code is the solution -

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
}

response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY', headers=headers, verify=True,timeout=(5, 14))
print(response.content)
```

It works perfectly on my laptop but it is not working on Google Collab or Heroku server or digital ocean as well as in motion hosting.

**What is the catch here?**

Comment: it seems this page uses JavaScript to load data and `requests` can't run JavaScript.You may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: No No, it doesn't. I am pretty sure of its structure. Selenium works fine but adds huge latency to the code.

I have also tried that with `requests-html` module.

Also, my script works most of the time. This has to do with some blocking from their end in a tricky manner.

Comment: when I turn off JavaScript in browser and load page then I see nothing. So JavaScript has to be important for this page.

Comment: you could try to use `requests.Session()` to get fresh cookies from main page and then use it on this page - maybe it will help. Every request may need own session ID. Maybe If you use old cookies then server may not find it in database and send wrong data.

Comment: OR maybe you made many requests in short time and it simply blocks you as bot. Maybe you even get HTML with warning or captcha - you could check it directly or sava in file and open in browser. It would need to use proxy server.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't worked. So reverted back. :( The server is not looking for cookies. It is more with the header function I think.

Comment: server sends cookies in headers.

Comment: Correct. The rule is - It blocks your IP if you scrap it within 3 minutes more than 100 times. I never break it. I scrap once in 5 to 10 mins. They also give list of blocked IPs publicly.

Comment: Oh, the cookies part. In some pages, I am able to scrap it using the headers mentioned here.

`response = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY', headers=headers)`

If you use this, it will work most of the time. (Note the params are hardcoded and ^ is forcifully removed)

Comment: maybe use `s = requests.Session()` and `r = s.get("https://www.nseindia.com/")` to get fresh cookies and then `s.get(your_url)` to get your page using fresh cookies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204695/discussion-between-amit-ghosh-and-furas).

Comment: I made loop to load it 200 times and I don't have any problem to get data from table. Maybe problem is something differen - i.e. temporaty problem with network.

Comment: or maybe Google doesn't like script which get data from other servers and it blocks them. This way Google Labs can't be used to spam other servers or to use Google Labs for illegal use.

Comment: @furas I've scrapped the same website before, hold on let me share for you

Comment: @AmitGhosh I've scrapped the same website before, hold on let me share for you

Comment: @furas Check the chat .. http://www.sharecsv.com/s/605ab5fe49530ca8ddf7434cf14bc40f/output.csv and https://bpaste.net/show/CPFKQ

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have no problem to scrape it - I run even loop to load it 200 times and it works correctly. It seems problem has only OP to run it on Google Labs. Maybe Google blocks it.

Comment: @furas just noticed it now from the comments

Comment: @furas if you can please have one more look. The code works perfectly in laptop (Win10 I use) but not working in any VPS so far.

Comment: you should check what you get in `response` - maybe VPS blocks access to some servers, or `nseindia` has these VPS on blacklist and it blocks access. For example PythonAnywhere has [whitlelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) of serevers which you can access from PythonAnywhere.

Comment: It generally gets stuck for infinite time and I get a timeout error. Is there any workaround in that cases?

Comment: @AmitGhosh where you able to finally fix it? What was the fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing in various environments, NSE blocks python-request as well as normal access to this website from most of the reputed cloud servers.

However, CURL works in DigitalOcean Bangalore and Amazon AWS Mumbai server. But if you convert that CURL data to Python request, that is blocked.

So here is a pythonic solution that will work in those cloud servers. It looks lame but I'm using it without digging deep -

```
import subprocess
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

subprocess.Popen('curl "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=BANKNIFTY" -H "authority: beta.nseindia.com" -H "cache-control: max-age=0" -H "dnt: 1" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36" -H "sec-fetch-user: ?1" -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" -H "sec-fetch-site: none" -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8" --compressed  -o maxpain.txt', shell=True)

f=open("maxpain.txt","r")
var=f.read()
print(var)
```

It basically runs the curl function and sends the output to a file and read the file back. That's it.

**Update ->** I added this a GitHUB Library. The above written answer is basically the `curl` method listed below

Use the nsefetch() function as documented here https://unofficed.com/nse-python/documentation/nsefetch/

In case you want `python-requests` method

```
from nsepython import *
payload= nsefetch('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
print(payload)
```

In case you want `curl` method

```
from nsepythonserver import *
payload= nsefetch('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
print(payload)
```

Comment: it is place for answer/solution, not for your comments or new information. You should put it in question.